# In-Game Asset Downloads Using Play Asset Delivery - Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-core, android-asset-delivery

I am making a game and it is going to have a lot of assets in the game and the download size is going to be very big. I am using the [Play Asset Delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity) to upload my large game to Play Store. More than 90% of the assets are maps. I have a few maps in the game and I don't want them all to be downloaded when the player is installing the game from the Google Play Store. Like Call of Duty Mobile I want the player to be able to download each map individually in runtime.

I separated the assets of every map into a separate assetBundle.

I read the Play Asset Delivery documentation and it seems like I have to use On-demand for each assetBundle.

But the when I build the game and upload it to play store it will download the whole game again. I don't know how to make it not download the on-demand assetBundles.

How do I do that?

is it event possible?

And sorry if my English was bad.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the reference on how you retrieve the assets: [Unity Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-unity)

Basically you need to import the Play Asset Delivery library and call the RetrieveAssetBundleAsync() method to retrieve an AssetBundle.

You can also request asset asynchronously and monitor the download progress.

Here's another reference on how you download the assets. [Retrieve assests](https://github.com/google/play-unity-plugins/issues/75)

Comment: Thanks. But all of the assetPacks are downloaded in install time. and there is nothing left to download in runtime

Comment: there's option to use install-time, fast-follow, or on-demand for the assetPacks. You can choose on-demand option if you want to download it in runtime